# Calculating two gradients in pytorch and reusing an intermediate gradient

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation

Suppose we have a function f whose gradient is slow to compute, and two functions `g1` and `g2` whose gradient is easy to compute. In `pytorch`, how can I calculate the gradients of `z1 = g1(f(x))` and `z2 = g2(f(x))` with respect to x, without having to calculate the gradient of f twice?

Example:

```
import torch
import time

def slow_fun(x):
    A = x*torch.ones((1000,1000))
    B = torch.matrix_exp(1j*A)
    return torch.real(torch.trace(B))

x = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
y = slow_fun(x)
z1 = y**2
z2 = torch.sqrt(y)

start = time.time()
z1.backward(retain_graph = True)
end = time.time()
print("dz1/dx: ", x.grad)
print("duration: ", end-start, "\n")

x.grad = None
start = time.time()
z2.backward(retain_graph = True)
end = time.time()
print("dz2/dx: ", x.grad)
print("duration: ", end-start, "\n")
```

This prints

```
dz1/dx:  tensor(-1673697.1250)
duration:  1.5571658611297607

dz2/dx:  tensor(-13.2334)
duration:  1.3989012241363525
```

so calculating `dz2/dx` takes about as long as calculating `dz1/dx`.

The calculating of `dz2/dx` could be sped up if `pytorch` would store `dy/dx` during the calculation of `dz1/dx`, and then reuse that result during the calculation of `dz2/dx`.

Is there a mechanism built into `pytorch` to achieve such a behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can decouple the nested function using chain rule. However, there will be some differences due to numerical issues.

```py
import torch
import time

def slow_fun(x):
    A = x*torch.ones((1000,1000))
    B = torch.matrix_exp(1j*A)
    return torch.real(torch.trace(B))

# baseline z1
x = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
y = slow_fun(x)
z1 = y**2
z1.backward()
dz1_dx = x.grad
print(dz1_dx)
> tensor(-1648274.2500)

# baseline z2
x = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
y = slow_fun(x)
z2 = torch.sqrt(y)
z2.backward()
dz2_dx = x.grad
print(dz2_dx)
> tensor(-13.1979)

# compute just dy/dx
x = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad = True)
y = slow_fun(x)
y.backward()
dy_dx = x.grad

# detach y to prevent full backprop
y1 = y.detach()
y1.requires_grad = True
z1 = y1**2
z1.backward()
dz1_dy = y1.grad
# compute gradient with chain rule
dz1_dx = dz1_dy * dy_dx
print(dz1_dx)
> tensor(-1672148.5000)

# detach y to prevent full backprop
y2 = y.detach()
y2.requires_grad = True
z2 = torch.sqrt(y2)
z2.backward()
dz2_dy = y2.grad
# compute gradient with chain rule
dz2_dx = dz2_dy * dy_dx
print(dz2_dx)
> tensor(-13.1980)
```

Comment: I understand there are numerical issues, but why is the difference so large?

Comment: For this specific case, the numerical issues come from the matrix exponential. If you remove that (ie have `slow_fun` compute `torch.real(torch.trace(x*torch.ones((1000,1000))))`), the difference is substantially smaller. My guess is the matrix exponential backward function is poorly conditioned

Answer (score 0):

To complement the answer of [@Karl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78063717/6331369), here is an alternative solution that doesn't require detaching tensors. It uses [`torch.autograd.functional.jacobian`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.functional.jacobian.html) to compute and extract the gradient. Here again, we compute `dy/dx` once and use its computation via the chain rule.

```
# compute dy/dx
dy_dx = jacobian(slow_fun, x)

# compute dz1/dx
dz1_dy = jacobian(lambda y: y**2, y)
dz1_dx = dy_dx*dz1_dy

# compute dz2/dx
dz2_dy = jacobian(lambda y: y.sqrt(), y)
dz2_dx = dy_dx*dz2_dy
```